# Postback after clicking a button does not react not for the first time in a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a webapplication with UserControls. When I click on a menu-item or a select-button in a grid, than I see that didn't react the first time. When I clicked for the second time then an event behind the button will fire.

What do I wrong? 
I've given the components a unique ID and the events are in the cs-files.

I hope someone can help me.

thanks.

---

The problems is in the two following examples:

```
 <asp:Menu ID="TabMenu" Width="100%" Height="25px" runat="server"         
                    Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="TabPages" 
                    StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False" 
                     AutoPostBack="true"  
                     OnMenuItemClick="DoMenuItemClick" > 
                <Items> 
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Domains" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
```

In this case for the first time, when you clicked on a menu-item, it looks like the page only is reloaded. And when clicks for the second time, the event really fires. In this example when you clicks on a menu-item, the right View is shown.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvwSelection" runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="True" 
        SelectedIndex="1"                 
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvwSelectie_SelectedIndexChanged"
        OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvwSelectie_SelectedIndexChanging" >
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#00257e" HorizontalAlign="Right" 
            BackColor="#FFFFFF"></PagerStyle>

    </asp:GridView>
```

Example 2: The first time you click on a selection button, then the row you touched is not selected. And after the first time everything works correct.

The ID's have a fixed name.
The AutoPostBack is set to True.
There is an event linked.
The grids has DataBinded.
There is site.master a default.aspx and the UserControls are placed in a Placeholder.

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found and solved the problem.

I have a dynamic UserControl FAddress and everytime he is wearing another control.
So I added the following row in the method: **FAddress.ID = "UserControl1";**

The problem was, that the control was loading everytime. By giving this dynamic control a fixed ID, this item has solved.

```
private void LoadPage(string APageName)
{
    FAddress = null;
    PlaceholderAddressTemplate.Controls.Clear();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(APageName))
    {
        FAddress = (UserControl)LoadControl(string.Format("~/UserControls/{0}.ascx",
                    APageName));

        if (FAddress != null)
        {
            FAddress.ID = "UserControl1";

            PlaceholderAddressTemplate.Controls.Add(FAddress);
            ShowOrHideComponents();
            FAddress.Focus();
        }
        else
            ShowOrHideComponents();
    }
    else
    ShowOrHideComponents();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the autopostback property is set to true behind your button, that may solve your problem.